# How to add tolerance to my cgal triangle?

Tags: cgal

I am using cgal's intersection method to find the intersection between line 
and a triangle.

```
double tolerance = 1e-6; 
auto result = intersection(segment1, triangle1);
```

Now I want to add tolerance in the triangle (similar to dilating the 
triangle by given tolerance amount).

So, How do I add tolerance to my triangle1?

ps : I saw that Bbox_3.h has dialte functionality.

Update :

Earlier I had

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> IK;

IK::Triangle_3 first_triangle(IK::Point_3(0, 0, 0), IK::Point_3(2, 0, 0),
                                IK::Point_3(1, 1, 0));
```

Now I made it :

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false>> IK;

IK::Triangle_3 first_triangle(IK::Point_3(0, 0, 0), IK::Point_3(2, 0, 0),
                                    IK::Point_3(1, 1, 0));
```

I still cannot figure out how to add interval (my tolerance) to those points. It would be great if there was some example regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such tolerance in CGAL. What you can do is to use a kernel with intervals (`say CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<> >`) and have the coordinates of the points of your triangles being intervals rather than a single value. Then all predicates with return [`Uncertain`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/STL_Extension/classCGAL_1_1Uncertain.html) objects that you can query using free functions (like `is_certain()`). There is also some pseudo code on [that page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/STL_Extension/classCGAL_1_1Uncertain.html).

Comment: "on that page". On which page?

Comment: added a linked to make it explicit.

Comment: So earlier I had `typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> IK;   IK::Triangle_3 first_triangle(IK::Point_3(0, 0, 0), IK::Point_3(2, 0, 0),
                                IK::Point_3(1, 1, 0));`. Now I mae it `typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false>> IK;` So now how do I add the tolerance to those Point_3 ?

Comment: Each point is now of type `CGAL::Interval_nt<false>`, so you can provide an interval for each coordinate of the points. When you construct your points, provide an interval instead of a double.

Comment: @sloriot Can you give me one example of how to place interval instead of double for a point. I saw through examples but could not find one.

Comment: Something like [that](https://gist.github.com/sloriot/4815f629b4051299b3665f202aa68617). Note that as soon as you have some input that are not in general position, you will have an unknown result (due to predicates that could not be evaluated safely). In your case, you might want to start with doing some `Bbox_2` overlap tests.

Comment: @sloriot ok I will try your example and let you know. Thank you for the help.